# Passing parameter in elementor from loop to popup contact form

Tags: wordpress, contact-form, elementor

I'm trying to use the post title field from a custom post loop (created with Ele Custom Skin) inside a popup contact form. Every post from the loop has a button that opens a popup which contains a contact form (I also use Elementor Pro to build this form) and I want that the default value of one of the text areas to be the title of the post (from the custom post loop). My question is if there is any way to achieve this? I mention that if I set the default value dynamically to 'Post Title', it will show the title of the page containing the loop, not the title of the specific post(and that's logical).

Answer (score 0):

create a button with text widget on loop template

```
<a class="btncontact" href="#" data-title="[page_title]">CONTACT</a>
```

create shortcodes in functions.php theme

```
    function myshortcode_title(){
   return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'myshortcode_title' );
```

in popup template use html widget and paste this

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
var z = e;
if(z.path[0].getAttribute('data-title')){
document.getElementById("idtarget").innerHTML = z.path[0].getAttribute('data-title');
}
});
</script>
```

change 'idtarget'